# Pass array name as reference to function and use it

Tags: solidity, arrays

Having 10 arrays like

```
string[] public array_1
string[] public array_2
```

....

what I want to do is have a seter method where I pass the name of array and input so I can push elements to it. So something like below but that it works, dont know if it is possible and which syntax would work?

```
    function addElement(string memory input, string memory array_name) public onlyOwner returns(bool success)
     {
         {array}.push(input);
         return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage arrays are passed as reference.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract A {
    uint256[] public a;
    uint256[] public b;
    uint256[] public c;
    
    function foo(uint w, uint256 x) public {
        if (w == 0) {
            bar(a, x);
        } else if (w == 1) {
            bar(b, x);
        } else if (w == 2) {
            bar(c, x);
        }
    }
    
    function bar(uint256[] storage ar, uint256 x) internal {
        ar.push(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what you did but I dont understand still why cant we just do this.

   function bar(uint256[] storage ar, uint256 x) public {
            ar.push(x);
    }

and call it with  bar(a, x);
I mean I know it doesnt work and we get "data location must be memory or calldata" but wondering why do we need to do it this way in a non direct way?

Comment: What I mean is why can  solidity pass reference to array with bar(b, b.length, x);
but if I want to do the same with function that would take on parametars and pass it on. I cant seem to get it right, always some error if I try to define function like

bar2(string memory b,  ....);

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic I updated the contract to not use .length it works. I had used .length originally because I wanted to do something more complicated. `storage` can be passed as reference and pushed to, `memory` can also be passed as reference but you cannot push to it (memory arrays cannot grow once allocated). I'd suggest to avoid using string they are expensive, use bytes32 when possible.

Comment: Thnx on help, I got your original idea and made it work.